# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 - Laravel Websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

Im trying to set up laravel websockets on a homestead SSL vagrant box

which is https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets

Im getting the error

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

My pusher info is as follows

```
pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
```

with my ENV:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_KEY=193eac85dcfd18e61e3b
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=secret
PUSHER_APP_ID=ID
PUSHER_CLUSTER=eu
```

I have installed the package and started the service on my VM running
php artisan websockets:serve

my Bootstrap.js is:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '193eac85dcfd18e61e3b',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});
```

and im listening on like so:

```
 window.Echo.channel("chat").listen("MessageSent", e => {
      console.log(e);
      this.messages.push(e);
    });
```

Comment: What is the response body that is sent with the 200 Response?

Comment: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200 -= That is the response message

Comment: That's just the exception message. Can you view details of the request/response in browser dev-tools, under "network"?

Comment: I went to Inspect/network/ws and clicked messages and that is all that is there

Comment: did you solved this?

Comment: Hey mate did you solve that?